# Taking huge time to execute piepeline text classification model using sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, text-classification

I have created a pipeline  model for text classification using python ,Firstly i have tried on 30k records dataset it is working fine got the good results , but when it comes to huge data set like 50k or 1 laksh record data set not at all giving at any results in console even though it is taken more than 24 hours time ?
please suggest  will pipeline model  taking to execute  on huge data for text classification ?
i am not getting that what was the problem with pipeline text classification .

tfidfVector = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = textProfilerObj.textTokenizer)

```
    # Create the  pipeline  model to clean, tokenize, vectorize, and classify using tfidVector

    pipe = Pipeline([("cleaner", TextCleaner()),('vectorizer', tfidfVector),('classifier', modelObj)])

    #fit the data using pipeline  

    baypit=pipe.fit(self.trainX,self.trainY)
```